# cURL command a C# consola

Tags: c#, api, curl

vengo hace dias tratando de hacer funcionar estas lineas cURL, en una aplicacion de consola C#. Donde no tengo Exito.

Espero puedan hecharme algo de luz.

```
curl -X POST https://xxxxxxxxx/api/GetToken
-H "Accept: */*" 
-H "Content-Length: 0"
-H "client_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
-H "client_secret: xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Por linea de comando anda Perfecto.

Lamentablemente no puedo usar httpClient, ya que debo usar Framework 3.5-.

Les comparto mis intentos fallidos, para ver si alguno pueda encontrar algo..

// Usando WebCliente

```
string url = "https://xxxxxx/api/GetToken";
   
var client = new WebClient { BaseAddress = url };
        client.Headers.Clear();
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "*/*";
        client.Headers["ContentLength"] = "0";
        client.Headers["client_id"] = "xxxxxxxxx";
        client.Headers["client_secret"] = "xxxxxx";
        string rta= client.UploadString(url, "POST", "");
        Console.WriteLine(rta);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

resultado de este intento::

System.Net.WebException: 'Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío.'

Excepcion 1: IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.

Excepcion2: SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto

Ahora bien .. si el mismo codigo del webclient lo uso en esta web

dotnetfiddle -> [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

funciono perfectamente..me trajo todos los datos de esa api. Ahora si ya no se que pensar..

tengo antivirus y firewall.. totalemente desactivados..

Quedo atento a sus comentarios

Comment: hola el link de dotnetfiddle no se encuentra lo que hiciste https://dotnetfiddle.net/ solo que te lleva a la pagina

Comment: claro, solo hago referencia, que si mi codigo .. con las reales credenciales lo uso en esa web anda OK. El codigo es el mencionado arriba, tal cual.

Comment: puedes colocar tu codigo en dotnetfiddle? pues si solo mencionas la pagina y no colocas el codigo no sirve de nada que la referencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listo ..
solo me faltaba agregar una linea de seguridad TLS al comienzo de mi aplicacion.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; //TLS 1.2
```